# How to recover a deleted folder from Time Machine back-up disk?

Tags: hard-drive, time-machine, backup

I wanted to clean my external disk that I use to back up my mac, but I didn't do it right... I deleted the folder 'Mac's Name' with my back ups, but the weird thing is that there is no extra free space on my external disk. So I learned that you have to delete your back-up within the Time Machine Interface. But I can't recover this folder from the trash can because of this message: "The operation can’t be completed because backup items can’t be modified."

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't emptied the trashcan, then you can manually move the files back from the `/Volumes/<diskname>/.Trashes` directory inside a terminal window

**Note**: You need to be root, so first `sudo su -`
and then cd into the .Trashes directory, and use `mv * ..` should move and make them available again

Comment: I solved it myself with this forum post: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5198466
Apparently Apple suggest not to use terminal to remove or reset time machine backups...